# RHEL 7: missing cgroup after reboot instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, rhel, cgroups

I'm trying to limit resources by using cgroup. It's working fine until I reboot the instance.

I had checked and found that the cgroup was removed for some reason. This is my step to creating the cgroup:

```
# Create a cgroup
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/my_cgroup
# Add the process to it
echo $PID > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/my_cgroup/cgroup.procs

# Set the limit to 40MB
echo $((40 * 1024 * 1024)) > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/my_cgroup/memory.limit_in_bytes
```

I'm using AMI RHEL-7.5_HVM-20180813-x86_64, kernel version 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64.

Could you guys help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like cgroup config is not persistant across reboot. I personally am not very familar and can't test but you can have a look at [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch01). You need to configure `cgconfig` to persist your changes.